# How to get to the needed element via SASS

Tags: sass

Please, help me to understand how to get to the element using SASS and change the color for a marked element without adding .class or ID to the element. Thanks a lot
[image]

Comment: `.offer {
   .content_left {
       div {
          h3:nth-child(2) span {`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTML is like this

```
<div class="content__left">

  <div class="offer__item">
    <h3 class="offer__title">
      Lorem <span>Ipsum</span>
    </h3>
  </div>

  <div class="offer__item">
    <h3 class="offer__title">
      Lorem <span>Ipsum</span>
    </h3>

  </div>
</div>
```

and the SCSS will be

```
.content__left {
  .offer__item:nth-child(2) {
      .offer__title {
        span {
          color: red; // your style goes here
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Working fiddle [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/chb97kuz/1/)

Comment: @Perry Nomad please let me know if you want more specific answer

Comment: I think this will add color red to all spans of all .offer__item elements on the page!

Comment: @PerryNomad i have updated my answer. please check and let me know.

Comment: Cool - thank you very much!!! How can I make it shorter without the long nesting- in css its seems toooo long))).                                                                              .content__left .offer__item:nth-child(2) .offer__title span {
  color: red;
}

Comment: the solution i gave is the shortest as per your requirement :) if you want to target child without adding `class` or `id`, you will have to use nesting.